# MongoDB update a document field in Array of Arrays

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to update ($set) a field "text" that matching "callback_data":"like" in document like this:

```
"data": {
    "buttons": [
        [{
            "text": "Button",
            "url": "https://example.org"
        }],
        [{
            "text": "",
            "callback_data": "like"
        }, {
            "text": "",
            "callback_data": "dislike"
        }]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/_g9YmDY5WMn

Use - [update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

[$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)  [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "data.buttons": {
        $map: {
          input: "$data.buttons",
          in: {
            $map: {
              input: "$$this", // array inside buttons 
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: [ "$$this.callback_data", "like" ] }, // condition
                  { $mergeObjects: [ "$$this", { text: "changed" } ] }, // true
                  "$$this" // false
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```